# How to import a multiple dump file in the same sid in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g

[image]I have tried to import a multiple dump file in the same dump file in oracle 11g database but, I cannot
import the dump file.

I have the sid of **ORCL**.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Could you explain it once again, with more details? Also, commands you used would help.

Comment: ... and please include any error messages, too.